# How to install google apps when android built from source

Tags: nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean

I added a kernel module to the msm flo kernel. I built android JB from source for my Nexus 7(flo). I flashed the device with the built OS. I can add 3rd party apps for which I have apks or I could add them to the source tree.

But I can't add google apps or anything from the play store. I can't add my google account under settings->add accounts since it doesn't exist. I tried installing google play store by downloading the apk to my machine and installing it with apk. Play store does install, but play store crashes as soon as I click on it.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

I am using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot more to the Google Apps than just downloading and installing the APK.  Google's Services framework and apps (a.k.a. GApps) are not part of AOSP which is probably where your source comes from, but they are required for Play Store and other apps to work properly.

Unfortunately GApps is closed-source, so it's not allowed to re-distribute these portions.  However, since your Nexus 7 tablet shipped with them, you should be able to easily find all the necessary components in the original image.  Alternatively, you should be able to find the GApps package for your specific Android OS version that works on your tablet over at [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7-2013/development) forums.

Answer (score 0):

You need the GoogleLoginService.apk and GoogleServicesFramework.apk installed in addition to the play store.

You can obtain the needed apks out of the [google apps package cyanogenmod makes available](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps), or just flash the entire thing.

If you want to do the one-at-a-time method, they also have [a listing of what all the system apks actually do](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Barebones) so you can decide if you want them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flash the Google Apps package for your device.

Head over to [Goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps). There'll be a guide there on which GApps build to download for a specific Android version.

Flash it through recovery. If you're having lots of FCs with Google apps after this, I'd suggest you reflash your Android build and then GApps immediately after. Don't forget to clear cache.